# Stray data using nested FOR loops - example sheet available

Tags: google-apps-script

SHEET HERE:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P7thpFW0XixHrUBIp_y6VEqoQqZ-IF_zRffguX6n87M/edit?usp=sharing

I am attempting to merge two sheets onto a third sheet, using text that is shared between the two original sheets.  Most of this code I have stolen from examples on this website and others.  Please review where my 'bug' is that creates a row at the end of the merged sheet with repeat text (but not a complete row of data.)

```
setnote sheet data:
NAME setnote
name1 setnote1
name2 setnote2

takenote sheet data:
NAME takenote
name1 takenote1
name2 takenote2

MERGE sheet data:
NAME setnote takenote
name1 setnote1 takenote1
name2 setnote2 takenote2       
      setnote1     <---- this is the stray data when script is run
```

Here is the code:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Merge Set Notes and Take List",
      functionName: "mergeDatav01"}, ];
  ss.addMenu("Merge Functions",menuEntries); 
}


function mergeDatav01(){

var mergeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('MERGE');                     
var setNoteSheet = ss.getSheetByName('setnote');
var takeNoteSheet = ss.getSheetByName('takenote');

var setFileNameRange = setNoteSheet.getRange(2, 1, setNoteSheet.getLastRow(), setNoteSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var takeFileNameRange = takeNoteSheet.getRange(2, 1, takeNoteSheet.getLastRow(), takeNoteSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();                     

var mergeStartRow = 2;

for (var takeLoop = 0; takeLoop < takeFileNameRange.length; takeLoop++) {
    for (var setLoop = 0; setLoop < setFileNameRange.length; setLoop++) {
      if (takeFileNameRange[takeLoop][0] == setFileNameRange[setLoop][0].toString().match(takeFileNameRange[takeLoop][0])) {
        var row = mergeStartRow + takeLoop
        mergeSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1).setValue(takeFileNameRange[takeLoop][0]);
        mergeSheet.getRange(row, 2, 1).setValue(setFileNameRange[setLoop][1]);
        mergeSheet.getRange(row, 3, 1).setValue(takeFileNameRange[takeLoop][1]);                                        
        break;
      break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code a little. Plus I don't think that you need the match function. I copied your data and changed the page names to set,tak and merge. I changed some of the names of variables and used getDataRange() because it's easier to use and less to type.

```
function mergeDatav01()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mergeSht=ss.getSheetByName('merge');                     
  var setSht=ss.getSheetByName('set');
  var takSht=ss.getSheetByName('tak');
  var setVals=setSht.getDataRange().getValues();
  var takVals=takSht.getDataRange().getValues();                     
  var mergeStartRow=2;
  for (var i=1;i<takVals.length;i++) 
  {
    for (var j=1;j<setVals.length;j++) 
    {
      if (takVals[i][0]==setVals[j][0]) 
      {
        var row=[];
        row.push(takVals[i][0],setVals[j][1],takVals[i][1]);
        mergeSht.appendRow(row);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what my merge sheet looks like after running this code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formulaic way of doing it if you didn't want to mess with Google Apps Script...

**Formula in Merge A2**

```
=Filter(setnote!A2:A,setnote!A2:A<>"")
```

**Formula in Merge B2**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"",VLOOKUP(A2:A,setnote!A:B,match("setnote",setnote!$1:$1,0),FALSE),""))
```

**Formula in Merge C2**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"",VLOOKUP(A2:A,takenote!A:B,match("takenote",takenote!$1:$1,0),FALSE),""))
```

**OR... you could combine it all and put this in Merge A2**

```
={Filter(setnote!A2:A,setnote!A2:A<>""),ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Filter(setnote!A2:A,setnote!A2:A<>"")<>"",VLOOKUP(Filter(setnote!A2:A,setnote!A2:A<>""),setnote!A:B,match("setnote",setnote!$1:$1,0),FALSE),"")),ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Filter(setnote!A2:A,setnote!A2:A<>"")<>"",VLOOKUP(Filter(setnote!A2:A,setnote!A2:A<>""),takenote!A:B,match("takenote",takenote!$1:$1,0),FALSE),""))}
```

I'm happy to explain any of them if you need.